# Referencing NuGet packages from directory in solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget

I have a solution with several ASP.NET Core projects in it, managed in Visual Studio 2015.

My NuGet packages are currently being stored in `C:\Users\My User\.nuget\packages\`. I need to instead have a Packages directory in my solution and reference packages from there. Like this:

- SolutionFolder

  - src

    - Project1
    - Project2
    - [...]
  - Packages

I copied the packages from the default path above into a solution directory, then removed all references for a project. I then added my Packages directory as a NuGet Package Source. Finally, I clicked Manage NuGet Packages and added some to a specific project, making sure that my custom package source was selected.

This seemed to work, but when I checked the path of the referenced packages, it was still the default `C:\Users\[...]\packages\` path.

What am I missing? How do I reference the packages from the solution directory?

I tried opening up the .xproj file and manually setting the path like I used to sometimes do in .csproj files, but it appears that isn't possible in .xproj files. Or I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I copied the packages from the default path above into a solution directory...it was still the default C:\Users[...]\packages\ path

You may mix up the concept "`repositoryPath`" and "`Packages source`".

Although you removed all references, added my Packages directory as a NuGet Package Source, install reference from custom package source, you just only  change the Packages source. **Once you install the packages from the custom package source, NuGet will download the packages from the custom package source and set those download packages to the default `repositoryPath`, then install those packages from default `repositoryPath` to your project**. So it was still in the default path.

If you want to change packages default location for **.net core** project, you can set "NUGET_PACKAGES" environment variable. Just Set "NUGET_PACKAGES" = "c:\teampackages". Or you can place a NuGet.Config file next to the solution with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <config>
      <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\packages" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

For the detail info, you can refer to [the same issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/626) on GitHub.

**However**, what I want to say is that you might not be happy with the results. Because .Net Core projects rely on so many NuGet packages. Almost hovering around 1GB. I think you will not want to set all those packages for each solution. Besides, with this change, you need to set up additional sources in VS for every solution. It`s quite inconvenient for .net core project. This is the reason why NuGet team set the special settings for .net core projects.

Answer (score 1):

> You can create a Nuget.config in your src directory and set the
>   repositoryPath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\packages" />
  </config>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local nuget repository for offline development and instead of having a packages directory use local repo. here is guide:

[CREATING A LOCAL NUGET REPOSITORY FOR OFFLINE DEVELOPMENT](https://codurance.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository/)